# PicklistValueInfo does not returns Custom object's picklist records but only returns standard object's picklist records

Tags: soql, picklist

So i executed this below query and it successfully returned records,

`SELECT DurableId,EntityParticleId,Id,IsActive,IsDefaultValue,Label,ValidFor,Value FROM PicklistValueInfo where EntityParticleId = 'Case.Type'`

but when i queried the same for **custom object's picklist** as shown below, it returns no records

`SELECT DurableId,EntityParticleId,Id,IsActive,IsDefaultValue,Label,ValidFor,Value FROM PicklistValueInfo where EntityParticleId = 'Student__c.Hobby__c'`

does **PicklistValueInfo** only works on Standard Objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below steps:

```
SELECT Id, DurableId
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinitionId ='Client_Master__c'<Object Name>
AND QualifiedAPIName = 'Status__c' <Picklist>
```

[image]

```
SELECT DurableId,EntityParticleId,Id,IsActive,IsDefaultValue,Label,ValidFor,Value 
FROM PicklistValueInfo 
where EntityParticleId = '01I3SXXXXXXNufS.00N3S000002Zi9s'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked @Tamil, but i want to know why this does not work with directly from PicklistValueInfo ? does it not support the customObject and why does it works on standard Object can you give me a explanation ?

Answer (score 1):

Or in one step...

```
SELECT Value,Label,IsActive
FROM PicklistValueInfo 
WHERE EntityParticle.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Client_Master__c'
AND EntityParticle.QualifiedApiName = 'Status__c'
```